# Windows 10 freeze and then hard reboot

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, freeze, reboot

[Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3gEq.png)

[OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB38M.png)

So this already happened from a long time, not just after Fall Creators Update. The freeze happened at random times, but I noticed that whenever I watch Youtube or Twitch most of the times it will freeze. The whole PC freeze and then after a minute it will auto reboot. It occured when I just browsing or working or gaming too.

What I've already done :

- Fresh Windows installation (didn't work)
- chkdsk (nothing wrong)
- sfc scannow (nothing wrong)
- memtest (nothing wrong)
- changing browser in case Chrome is the culprit (still froze)
- disabling hardware acceleration (didn't work)
- looking for crash dump (found nothing at C:\Windows\Minidump and can't find MEMORY.DMP either)
- looking at reliability monitor (only lists "Windows was not properly shut down" at the time of freeze)

I also tried using CrystalDiskInfo and noticed something. [One of my HDD information is missing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWQiA.png) The other HDD [is fine though.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hafR.png) On speccy screenshot above, the temperature of this HDD is also missing. Could it be the culprit?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Standard approach is to configure the computer to create a "Complete" or "Active" dump when you have the hang.  You can initiate this using the keyboard. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard  I would suggest as soon as you notice the hang the better.  From there it's a case of using Winbg to analyze it.  This is typically far from simple in a hang situation but this is the professional approach to the issue you have.  I would say share it but as it contains all of active memory, this is too much of a security concern.

Comment: Defrag Tools #179 - Manually Generating a Crash Dump
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-179-Manually-Forcing-a-Crash-Dump

Defrag Tools #137 - Debugging Kernel Mode Crashes and Hangs
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/DefragTools-137-Debugging-kernel-mode-dumps